# In IE9 overflow-y hidden removes all scroll bars

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, overflow

Is there any known reason overflow-y: hidden will remove all scroll bars in IE9?

I've put this in an IE9 only style sheet like this:

```
body,html {
    overflow-x: auto !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the scrollbar won't show up with auto unless it NEEDS to. Are you sure it needs to. Is there anything on the X axis to scroll to? `overflow-x: scroll` should put it on there.

Comment: yes, I can make the window hight 300px high and the page is 1000px high. It should scroll but no dice. Removing overflow-y: hidden fixes the issue.

Comment: Ummm.... X is left to right. So the height won't change the X scroll bar.

Comment: yeah, I just realized that as I was responding the last time. I"m sorry. I just so burned out on this project. If you even knew the insanity I was handed... you give me a hug and a beer. 1 more day till the weekend.

Comment: @dcp3450: I posted an answer, but after seeing the comments I removed it since it doesn't really apply to your actual problem. That said, I'm really sorry to hear what you're going through :( Can't buy you a beer, but here's all the best to you for your project!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a genius and had my x and y switched. For future developers that see this. Get sleep, it really helps.

Answer (score 0):

The overflow: hidden property will hide any content that will flow out of the normal boundary of the elements box model. In this case you are setting it to the html, so anything that overflows will hide instead of having the scroll bars. Give this a try and see how this works:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is a great article on all the different overflow properties available and how they work: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/